# adding item from edit text to spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

Im tring to add the text thats in an edittext to the spinner when the submit buttin is clicked...

I already have 3 entries in the spinner which are showing up, but the string I make from the edit text is not entering into it.

```
    public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {
    FoodSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Bread");
    list.add("Sugar");
    list.add("Steak");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    FoodSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String ET = editText.getText().toString();

            if (!ET.equals("")) {
                list.add("" + ET + "");
            }

        }





    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It adds the item, simply you don't "refresh" the adapter:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String ET = editText.getText().toString();
    if (!ET.equals("")) {
        list.add(ET);
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you this resolved the problem (i had a problem unrelated to my first question which is why I initially thought this wasn't the solution)

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside the if statement

```
dataAdapter.add("" + ET + "");
dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
FoodSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```